# Insert associative PHP arrays into mysql without typing every individual insert name and value

Tags: php, mysql

This is my first time asking a question so sorry if I am unclear. My goal is to have an html form create an associative array (`$_Session`) and then have that array submitted to a MySQL database table. My `$_Session` array is going to get very long so I was wondering if there is a way to submit the array where the keys are the MySQL table column names and the values are inserted under the column name.

I am aware that I can code something similar to

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
        VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";
```

but my issues with that is I would have to type out each insert name and value. Could there possibly be a foreach loop to go through the array and insert everything without having to type out each individual key to the array?

Comment: Well typically you would use `$_POST`, and then you can simply loop over all of the `name` values stored in `$_POST`. Is there a particular reason you're making use of `$_SESSION`?

Comment: You can use prepared statements: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: @Obsidian Age I am using ````$_SESSION```` because I use the values on other php pages as well. My hope is to have the ````$_SESSION```` array submitted just before the user closes out of the page.

Comment: @Obsidian Age Can you give me an example of how to use the loop with the ````name```` values?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can do this using `mysqli` prepared statements, which will help protect you if any of the variable data comes from the internet. Note that every mysqli statement has error checking so if this isn't exactly right for your environment you should quickly see where the issue is.

```
$_SESSION = ["firstname" => "John", "lastname" => "Doe", "email" => "john@example.com", "age" => 24] ;

// create the query
$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (" .
        implode(',', array_keys($_SESSION)) .
        ') VALUES (' .
        implode(',', array_fill(0, count($_SESSION), '?')) .
        ')';
echo $sql;

// prepare the query (assuming mysqli, connection $conn)
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql) or die($conn->error);
// prepare the variable types for the bind
$types = '';
foreach ($_SESSION as $value) {
    if (is_int($value)) $types .= 'i';
    elseif (is_numeric($value)) $types .= 'd';
    else $types .= 's';
}
// need to get the values into a numerically indexed array for the splat operator
$values = array_values($_SESSION);
$stmt->bind_param($types, ...$values) or die($conn->error);
$stmt->execute() or die($stmt->error);
```

Note that if the keys of the `$_SESSION` array are derived from user input, you still need to check that they are valid to completely protect yourself from SQL injection. The ideal way to do that would be to compare them against a list of the actual column names in `MyGuests`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This looks very promising but I get the following "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot unpack array with string keys in...." any thoughts?

Comment: @TommyBacher sorry - forgot the splat operator only works on numerically indexed arrays. See my edit.

Comment: This worked! I've spent all day on this, who knew it was this easy. I can't thank you enough.

Comment: Note you're still vulnerable to SQL injections on the field names.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Given that the data has been transferred to `$_SESSION`, it's probably reasonable to assume the field names are hardwired rather than the result of user input. But it's a good point, I will make a note about it.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want we can use `array_walk` (or just a regular `foreach` loop) to process each key-val pair.

We take care to add enclosing `""` around string values.

Finally, we can use the `INSERT INTO ... SET` structure to easily get what we want into the query (rather than `INSERT INTO ... VALUES`).

```
<?php

$_SESSION = ["firstname" => "John", "lastname" => "Doe", "email" => "john@example.com", "age" => 24] ;

// we "accumulate" the result in $arr
array_walk($_SESSION, function($v, $k) use (&$arr) {

    // add quotes around strings
    $val = is_numeric($v)?$v:"\"$v\""; 

    $arr[] = "$k = $val";
});

$list = implode(", ", $arr);

$query = "INSERT INTO MyGuests SET $list";

echo $query; //INSERT INTO MyGuests SET firstname = "John", lastname = "Doe", email = "john@example.com", age = 24
```

[Demo Code](https://3v4l.org/u3pmn)

Word of warning: you shouldn't trust any input from the internet. At the very least, you need to ensure that every key in $_SESSION is a valid column name, and you need to make every value safe against [SQL-injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).